# How to pass Poco::SharedPtr to a TimerCallback function?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I have created a Timer with Poco following the example:

```
TimerExample example;
Timer timer(250, 500);
timer.start(TimerCallback<TimerExample>(example, &TimerExample::onTimer));
```

However I for my case TimerExample need to be a Poco::SharedPtr as

```
Poco::SharedPtr<TimerExample>TimerExample;
```

The constructor of TimerCallback takes the following parameters :

```
TimerCallback(
     C & object,
     Callback method
);
```

Where C is the template Class `<TimerExample>` for our case.
I'd like to know how to pass the Poco::SharedPtr  to the TimerCallback function in order to be consistent with the bullet from relevant poco guide 030-MemoryManagement.pdf where it is stated that:

> Once you use SharedPtr for an object, never work with plain pointers
>   to that object again.

Comment: This looks weird; as `TimerCallback` constructor takes reference to the `TimerExample` instance you can't pass the shared pointer to it no matter what you do (you'll always end up with a reference, while you need to keep a copy of the shared pointer). I reckon you need to derive a `TimerCallback` descendant that would keep copy of the shared pointer and call its ancestor's method to execute the callback when the time is ripe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment by vencik - you can't. As it currently stands, you can only pass in a reference to the object having the callback as member and you have to make sure it is valid during the lifetime of the TimerCallback instantiation - your callback can be SharedPtr that you can deref to pass in, but the TimerCallback will take its address and will know nothing about its sharing elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Regarding the automatic delete of the SharedPtris it possible the above handling to create any abnormal situation that may lead to a memory leak?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is already mentioned above: do not access `TimerExample` after the last SharedPtr instance holding pointer to it is destructed.